# Изображение передается некорректно при запросе put django

Tags: python, django

Картинка получена через форму:

```
class CustomUploadFileForm(forms.Form):
   file = forms.FileField())
```

Помимо картинок через эту же форму загружаются и файлы любых других форматов. Я пытаюсь загрузить картинку, полученную из формы, через API OpenstackSwift Swift, я вижу черный фон с небольшим белым квадратом, файлы остальные форматы (pdf, text и тд) загружаются и просматриваются нормально . В чем может быть ошибка? Прилагаю сам джанговский запрос.

```
class CustomUploadView(FormView):
    ...
    form_class = ObjectStorageCreateObjectForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        file: InMemoryUploadedFile = self.request.FILES['file']
        headers = {'Content-Type': file.content_type, 'X-Auth-Token': ...}
        requests.request(
            method='PUT', url=...,
            headers=headers, verify=..., files={'file': file}
        )
    return super().form_valid(form)
```